# Android- show, update and remove the imageview on specific time without referesh the activity

Tags: android

In Activity I need to show one image on layout when time reaches 2PM every day upto 4PM. After that I need to update that imageview with another image. And it should happen without refreshing the screen. So please suggest the best way to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: use service(for calling new image) with local broadcast listener (to make activity aware image is coming) and make a function where you update the imageview as per local broadcast listener.

Answer (score 0):

I see, AlarmManager, Broadcast Receiver, and rather simple manipulation, there's no refresh() to call, unless you do mean something else.